# AutoIT Page/Window Object Model

Tags: user-interface, testing, automation, autoit, testautomationfx

I would like to ask if we can also achieved a Page/Window Object Model in AutoIT? Majority of my project assignment was on Web Automation and I'm using Selenium Webdriver with Framework uses Page Object Model. Currently, I'm assigned to a project for GUI automation. I like to implement this kind of approach also in AutoIT if feasible so that I can reuse the objects to other classes. We are planning to use AutoIT standalone. I noticed that  most of the example available in the internet was the object created on each class/script.

Your insights are highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more information about your application (AUT). Then maybe I can increase my answer below with more details or recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General:**

That common approach of using the **Page Object Model (POM) Design Pattern** isn't quit good feasible with AutoIt. Of course you can create a object structure with AutoIt too, but it was not intended for the language. Anyway, some of the goals of POM can be achieved with the following example suggestion of a test structure.

**Please notice:**

Since you don't provide enough information about your *application under test (AUT)*, I explain a basic structure. The implementation depends on your application (SWING/RCP, WinForm etc.). It's also important which tool support do you need for your page object recognition. Besides *WinForm* that could be controled by `ControlCommand` functions in AutoIt, it's a proper way to use **UIASpy** or **au3_uiautomation** as helper tools.

- [UIASpy - UI Automation Spy Tool](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/196833-uiaspy-ui-automation-spy-tool/)
- [au3_uiautomation](https://github.com/jvanegmond/au3_uiautomation)

It's an advantage to know the POM structure in context with Selenium. I usually include a test case description with *behavior driven development* BDD (Gherkin syntax with Cucumber or SpecFlow), but this will not be a part of that example here.

**Example structure:**

[image]

The structure consists of two applications under test *Calc* and *VlcPlayer*. Both follow the common structure *PageObjects* and *Tests*. You should try to devide your page objects (files) in many subfolders to keep an overview. This substructure should be similar for the *Tests* folder/subfolders.

In the *Tests* area you could include several test stages or test categories depending on your test goals (Acceptance/UI tests, just functional smoke tests and so on). It's also a good idea to control the execution order by an separat wrapper file, **TestCaseExecutionOrder.au3**. This should exist for all test categories to avoid a mixing of them.

This wrapper au3 file contains the function calls, it's the processing start/control.

**Approach description:**

- TestCaseExecutionOrder.au3

  - Calls the functions which are the test cases in the subfolders (Menu, PlaylistContentArea, SideNavigation).
  - Test case *NiceName* consists of some test steps.

    - These test steps have to be included into that script/file by:

      ```cpp
      #include-once ; this line is optional
      #include "Menu\OpenFolder.au3"
      ```
    - Test step *OpenFolder.au3* (which is a part of a test case) contains the function(s) to do the folder loading and there content.

      - In that functions the PageObject *MenuItemMedia.au3* will be loaded/included into the script/file by:

        ```cpp
        #include-once ; this line is optional
        #include "..\..\..\PageObjects\Menu\MenuItemMedia.au3"
        ```

        - File *MenuItemMedia.au3* should only contain the recognition mechanism for that area and actions.

          - This could be *find menu item Media* (as a function).
          - or *find open folder menu item* (as a function) and so on.

            ```cpp
            Func _findMenuItemMedia()
                ; do the recognition action
                ; ...

                Return $oMenuItem
            EndFunc
            ```
    - In the test step *OpenFolder.au3* which calls `_findMenuItemMedia()` like:

      ```cpp
      Global $oMedia = _findMenuItemMedia()
      ```

      can a `.click` executed or something like `.getText` etc.

The test cases should only `#include` the files which are necessary (test steps). The test steps should also only `#include` the necessary files (page objects) and so on. So it's possible to adjust the recognition functions once and it can be used in the corresponding test steps.

**Conclusion:**

Of course it's hard to explain it in this way, but with this approach you can do a similar way like in Selenium for *web testing*. Please notice that you properbly have to use `Global` variables often. You have to be ensure the correct *includings* and don't lose the overview of your test, which is in OOP test based approaches much easier.

I recommend the usage of VS Code, because you can jump from file to file at the *#include statements*. That's pretty handy.

> I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Sven. This is very informative and helpful for my work. :)